# Task manager shortcut not working on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, task-manager

I have some problems with the Task Manager not always opening on Windows 8. I recently upgraded my pc from Windows 7 to Windows 8. And it seems that the Windows 8 Task Manager doesn't always pop up if I press the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

I have tried different times (on different occasions), always waiting afterwards to make sure it isn't slow. But it doesn't pop up in most cases. And then, in very rare cases, it does pop up if I press the shortcut.

If I use the other shortcuts to open the Task Manager it works almost immediately: via the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>or by pressing <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>T</kbd>.

Has somebody anything I could try to fix this? Is this a known bug? Are there maybe any other shortcuts that will work in Windows 8?

I am somebody who uses the task manager a lot, so it would be nice to have a working shortcut (the shorter, the better). I'm running the latest version of Windows 8 Pro (all updates installed).

Comment: I can't help you solve the problem, but I can at least let you know that I can't reproduce the issue on my copy of Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: I don't know if this could be an issue or not as it's intermittent but, do you have any keyboard mapping technology (like AutoHotKey) or an FN key?

Comment: No keyboard mapping applications are installed. I have an Fn key, which I don't really use that much. But I don't really think that could make a difference?